# Best practice for mysql relational database syncing to elastic search

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, relational-database

I have a user field which depends on lot of other fields, it has multiple foreign keys to other table and have many-to-many relation using pivot table and one to many relations.

The API is like the nested JSON structure. The relational data looks like this for a particular user.

```
user = {
  id : _212dasd,
  name: "alphabeta",
  key1_id = 23,
  key1 : {
     id: 23,
     name: "new name"
  },
  key2 : [
      {
         id: _asdak61526,
         key2_id : 2
         user_id : _212dasd,

      },
      {
         id: _asdak6152a,
         key2_id : 3
         user_id : _212dasd
      }
  ],
  key3: {
     name : "gama",
     key_3_nested : {
       name : "abc",
       key_3_nested_levle2 : {
            name : "xyz",
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

How can I have mysql relational data synced to elastic search, as most read will go with the elastic search, I am using log-stash for syncing.

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "root"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/~/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = users.id" // just a demo query
    schedule => "* * * * * *"
    }
  }
output {
  elasticsearch {
    document_id=> "%{sk_id}.%{user_id}"
    document_type => "doc"
    index => "db_prd"
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
  }
  stdout{
    codec => json_lines 
  }
}
```

Question: How can I maintain the relation, is creation multiple join query a good idea as every time it will make a multiple big join on lot of users data and its not optimised structure. 
For 10000 users and join to multiple tables will slow the sync. Will it sync the every index or only changed one?

How can I get the nested structure on the API from elastic search.

Comment: Did you get solution if yes Please post here

Comment: No it was causing a lot of overhead, I quit the logstash part and used the dynamic add and update, by calling the separate service on each  addition, single/bulk update.

Comment: No I didnt get that .Problem Statement: 
1: How to load relational data (5-6 big table ) to elastic search who have One to many relationship as mentioned in example 1st link below  
2: How to keep update elastic search data if any dependant information changes ? Below is the in detailed question post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64931204/strategy-to-bootstrap-huge-hierarchical-data-quickly-and-way-to-update-single-hi

Comment: I made the needed indexing of the data first, and flooded the data for the existing data that was in the database (did a lock for a time period at low traffic time), did mostly from slave database. Later on each new addition API,  it triggers an addition event to search service as well (not through logstash but add api for elastic search). Same thing on edit was done. Elasticsearch. For any relation data it checks all the services that are dependent. Say for an org info update it updates the all user related to that organisation.

Comment: Here is what I understand from your solution 
You are indexing required tables data in seperate index from replica DB e.g. Employee (name,age,general details etc), Contacts (contact details ) etc.
But can u elaborate on how did you "triggers an addition event" and "update event" for any change in contact or age ? Any specific framework like Kafka?
What does and API mean is that elastic search api like CRUD ? My Detailed problem statement can be found (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-use-case-and-implementation-approach/251082)_italic_

Comment: I think he did that on a back end framework. Most of them provide the option to trigger a series of method when an object is updated. This works fine, but doesn't scale really well.
The ecosystem of SQL => elasticsearch rivers is not well established yet, and if you want to update nested objects, based on updates of tables, you're in for a lot of work.

Our approach is when something gets updated, we identify all the dependencies, and we update each document as brand new one. This means we are reindexing not only what was updated, but also all the things that were not updated. suboptimal

Comment: I am currently looking for a way to do this and here are the options I found : 
1- Build the logic in your back end framework or use the elasticearch client, which varies depending on the language.
2- Debezium. Seems the most scalable option, but no open source project has been built yet.
3- use jbdc elasticsearch : https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc but the project hasn't been updated since 4 years as I am talking
4- use https://github.com/go-mysql-org/go-mysql-elasticsearch (project last updated a year ago)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jdbcstream in filter to add Nested object like:

```
jdbc_streaming {
            jdbc_driver_library => "/~/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
            jdbc_connection_string =>  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name"
            jdbc_user => "root"
            jdbc_password => "12345678@Abc"
            statement => "SELECT * FROM table2 ON table2.user_id = cus_id"
            parameters => {"cus_id" => "id"}
            target => "table2"
          }
```

It will create nested "table2" with data is row responsed from   statement => `"SELECT * FROM table2 ON table2.user_id = cus_id" with "id"` in statement => `"SELECT * FROM users;"` ( fix of this statement => `"SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = users.id"`)

Notice: It will slow your process